# How to get GoogleMobileAd SDK version from .framework file?

Tags: xcode, admob

Google recently announced:

> Beginning Jan 23, 2018, Google Mobile Ads SDK versions older than 7.0.0 for Android and 7.0.0 for iOS will no longer be supported. Publishers with these older versions will not be able to serve ads in their apps(s). Please ensure that you have upgraded to the latest version of the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

I have .framework file of GoogleMobileAds SDK but I don't know the version. Is somewhere in this file version of this framework written, so I know I'm in the safe zone?